# How to get unique identifiacation number of iphone

Tags: codenameone

I want to get unique id of iphone.currently I am using `Display.getInstance().getUdid();` but it gives different unique id each time I install an application on iphone.
Can you please let me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can no longer get the Unique id per device because of apples revised security policy . [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) is the best alternative you can go for.
You can try

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

NSString  *currentDeviceId = [[device identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by calling this function:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor
```

Answer (score 2):

`getUDID()` returns a faux number that can't be made unique due to Apple's restrictions.