# Codenameone:How to get unique identifiacation number of iphone

Tags: codenameone

I want to get unique id of iPhone.currently I am using `Display.getInstance().getUdid();` but it gives different unique id each time I install an application on iPhone. Its working fine in `Android`.

Can you please let me how to resolve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22167993/3145960

Comment: As per apple identifier for vendor  is a unique id for vendor.so can we get this number from i phone in codename one?

Comment: There's a plenty of libraries to generate a unique ID for iPhone. You may search for one of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037814/how-to-get-unique-identifiacation-number-of-iphone